# Messages not consumed on SEDA endpoint with the provided queue instance

Tags: java, asynchronous, apache-camel, blockingqueue

In the following camel context I have configured a SEDA endpoint with the provided `ArrayBlockingQueue`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd">

    <bean id="arrayQueue" class="java.util.concurrent.ArrayBlockingQueue">
        <constructor-arg index="0" value="10" /><!-- size -->
        <constructor-arg index="1" value="true" /><!-- fairness -->
    </bean>

    <camelContext id="camel" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
        <route id="sendRoute">
            <from uri="direct:send"/>
            <to uri="seda:send" />
        </route>
        <route id="sedaRoute">
            <from uri="seda:send?queue=#arrayQueue"/>
            <log message="My message: ${body}" loggingLevel="INFO"/>
        </route>
    </camelContext>
</beans>
```

However, the messages sent to the endpoint are not consumed.

`TRACE` level log when sending string `"abc"` to the `direct:send` route:

```
2016-06-03 19:53:19,231 TRACE [http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1] camel.impl.SharedProducerServicePool  No free services in pool to acquire for key: Endpoint[direct://send]

2016-06-03 19:53:19,231 TRACE [http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1] camel.support.ServiceSupport  Starting service

2016-06-03 19:53:19,232 DEBUG [http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1] component.direct.DirectProducer  Starting producer: Producer[direct://send]

2016-06-03 19:53:19,232 DEBUG [http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1] camel.impl.ProducerCache  Adding to producer cache with key: Endpoint[direct://send] for producer: Producer[direct://send]

2016-06-03 19:53:19,235 TRACE [http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1] impl.converter.DefaultTypeConverter  Converting java.lang.String -> java.lang.String with value: abc

2016-06-03 19:53:19,235 DEBUG [http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1] camel.impl.ProducerCache  >>>> Endpoint[direct://send] Exchange[Message: abc]

2016-06-03 19:53:19,237 TRACE [http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1] impl.converter.DefaultTypeConverter  Converting java.lang.String -> java.lang.String with value: abc

2016-06-03 19:53:19,237 TRACE [http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1] camel.impl.DefaultUnitOfWork  UnitOfWork created for ExchangeId: ID-DT-DBOZANOVIC-63893-1464976388425-0-1 with Exchange[Message: abc]

2016-06-03 19:53:19,239 TRACE [http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1] impl.converter.DefaultTypeConverter  Converting java.lang.String -> java.lang.String with value: abc

2016-06-03 19:53:19,239 TRACE [http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1] camel.util.EventHelper  Notification of event is disabled: ID-DT-DBOZANOVIC-63893-1464976388425-0-1 exchange created: Exchange[Message: abc]

2016-06-03 19:53:19,240 TRACE [http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1] impl.converter.DefaultTypeConverter  Converting java.lang.String -> java.lang.String with value: abc

2016-06-03 19:53:19,240 TRACE [http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1] camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor  Processing exchange for exchangeId: ID-DT-DBOZANOVIC-63893-1464976388425-0-1 -> Exchange[Message: abc]

2016-06-03 19:53:19,240 TRACE [http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1] impl.converter.DefaultTypeConverter  Converting java.lang.String -> java.lang.String with value: abc

2016-06-03 19:53:19,240 TRACE [http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1] camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor  Processing exchange for exchangeId: ID-DT-DBOZANOVIC-63893-1464976388425-0-1 -> Exchange[Message: abc]

2016-06-03 19:53:19,241 TRACE [http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1] impl.converter.DefaultTypeConverter  Converting java.lang.String -> java.lang.String with value: abc

2016-06-03 19:53:19,241 TRACE [http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1] camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor  Processing exchange for exchangeId: ID-DT-DBOZANOVIC-63893-1464976388425-0-1 -> Exchange[Message: abc]

2016-06-03 19:53:19,241 TRACE [http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1] camel.processor.DefaultErrorHandler  isRunAllowed() -> true (Run allowed if we are not stopped/stopping)

2016-06-03 19:53:19,242 TRACE [http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1] impl.converter.DefaultTypeConverter  Converting java.lang.String -> java.lang.String with value: abc

2016-06-03 19:53:19,242 DEBUG [http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1] camel.processor.SendProcessor  >>>> Endpoint[seda://send] Exchange[Message: abc]

2016-06-03 19:53:19,244 TRACE [http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1] impl.converter.DefaultTypeConverter  Converting java.lang.String -> java.lang.String with value: abc

2016-06-03 19:53:19,245 TRACE [http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1] component.seda.SedaProducer  Adding Exchange to queue: Exchange[Message: abc]

2016-06-03 19:53:19,245 TRACE [http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1] impl.converter.DefaultTypeConverter  Converting java.lang.String -> java.lang.String with value: abc

2016-06-03 19:53:19,245 TRACE [http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1] camel.util.EventHelper  Notification of event is disabled: ID-DT-DBOZANOVIC-63893-1464976388425-0-1 exchange Exchange[Message: abc] sent to: Endpoint[seda://send] took: 3 ms.

2016-06-03 19:53:19,245 TRACE [http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1] impl.converter.DefaultTypeConverter  Converting java.lang.String -> java.lang.String with value: abc

2016-06-03 19:53:19,246 TRACE [http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1] camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor  to: Recording duration: 3 millis for exchange: Exchange[Message: abc]

2016-06-03 19:53:19,246 TRACE [http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1] camel.processor.DefaultErrorHandler  Is exchangeId: ID-DT-DBOZANOVIC-63893-1464976388425-0-1 interrupted? false

2016-06-03 19:53:19,246 TRACE [http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1] camel.processor.DefaultErrorHandler  Is exchangeId: ID-DT-DBOZANOVIC-63893-1464976388425-0-1 done? true

2016-06-03 19:53:19,246 TRACE [http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1] impl.converter.DefaultTypeConverter  Converting java.lang.String -> java.lang.String with value: abc

2016-06-03 19:53:19,246 TRACE [http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1] camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor  route: Recording duration: 6 millis for exchange: Exchange[Message: abc]

2016-06-03 19:53:19,247 TRACE [http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1] impl.converter.DefaultTypeConverter  Converting java.lang.String -> java.lang.String with value: abc

2016-06-03 19:53:19,247 TRACE [http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1] camel.impl.DefaultUnitOfWork  UnitOfWork done for ExchangeId: ID-DT-DBOZANOVIC-63893-1464976388425-0-1 with Exchange[Message: abc]

2016-06-03 19:53:19,247 TRACE [http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1] impl.converter.DefaultTypeConverter  Converting java.lang.String -> java.lang.String with value: abc

2016-06-03 19:53:19,247 TRACE [http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1] camel.util.EventHelper  Notification of event is disabled: ID-DT-DBOZANOVIC-63893-1464976388425-0-1 exchange completed: Exchange[Message: abc]

2016-06-03 19:53:19,248 TRACE [http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1] impl.converter.DefaultTypeConverter  Converting java.lang.String -> java.lang.String with value: abc

2016-06-03 19:53:19,248 TRACE [http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1] camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor  Exchange processed and is continued routed synchronously for exchangeId: ID-DT-DBOZANOVIC-63893-1464976388425-0-1 -> Exchange[Message: abc]

2016-06-03 19:53:19,248 TRACE [http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1] impl.converter.DefaultTypeConverter  Converting java.lang.String -> java.lang.String with value: abc

2016-06-03 19:53:19,248 TRACE [http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1] camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor  Exchange processed and is continued routed synchronously for exchangeId: ID-DT-DBOZANOVIC-63893-1464976388425-0-1 -> Exchange[Message: abc]

2016-06-03 19:53:19,248 TRACE [http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1] impl.converter.DefaultTypeConverter  Converting java.lang.String -> java.lang.String with value: abc

2016-06-03 19:53:19,248 TRACE [http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1] camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor  Exchange processed and is continued routed synchronously for exchangeId: ID-DT-DBOZANOVIC-63893-1464976388425-0-1 -> Exchange[Message: abc]

2016-06-03 19:53:19,248 TRACE [http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1] impl.converter.DefaultTypeConverter  Converting java.lang.String -> java.lang.String with value: abc

2016-06-03 19:53:19,248 TRACE [http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1] camel.util.EventHelper  Notification of event is disabled: ID-DT-DBOZANOVIC-63893-1464976388425-0-1 exchange Exchange[Message: abc] sent to: Endpoint[direct://send] took: 13 ms.
```

When using the default queue (by deleting `?queue=#arrayQueue` from the above camel context), the messages are consumed:

```
2016-06-03 19:50:40,333 TRACE [http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1] camel.impl.SharedProducerServicePool  No free services in pool to acquire for key: Endpoint[direct://send]

2016-06-03 19:50:40,334 TRACE [http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1] camel.support.ServiceSupport  Starting service

2016-06-03 19:50:40,334 DEBUG [http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1] component.direct.DirectProducer  Starting producer: Producer[direct://send]

2016-06-03 19:50:40,334 DEBUG [http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1] camel.impl.ProducerCache  Adding to producer cache with key: Endpoint[direct://send] for producer: Producer[direct://send]

2016-06-03 19:50:40,337 TRACE [http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1] impl.converter.DefaultTypeConverter  Converting java.lang.String -> java.lang.String with value: abc

2016-06-03 19:50:40,338 DEBUG [http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1] camel.impl.ProducerCache  >>>> Endpoint[direct://send] Exchange[Message: abc]

2016-06-03 19:50:40,340 TRACE [http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1] impl.converter.DefaultTypeConverter  Converting java.lang.String -> java.lang.String with value: abc

2016-06-03 19:50:40,340 TRACE [http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1] camel.impl.DefaultUnitOfWork  UnitOfWork created for ExchangeId: ID-DT-DBOZANOVIC-63763-1464976228255-0-1 with Exchange[Message: abc]

2016-06-03 19:50:40,341 TRACE [http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1] impl.converter.DefaultTypeConverter  Converting java.lang.String -> java.lang.String with value: abc

2016-06-03 19:50:40,341 TRACE [http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1] camel.util.EventHelper  Notification of event is disabled: ID-DT-DBOZANOVIC-63763-1464976228255-0-1 exchange created: Exchange[Message: abc]

2016-06-03 19:50:40,342 TRACE [http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1] impl.converter.DefaultTypeConverter  Converting java.lang.String -> java.lang.String with value: abc

2016-06-03 19:50:40,342 TRACE [http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1] camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor  Processing exchange for exchangeId: ID-DT-DBOZANOVIC-63763-1464976228255-0-1 -> Exchange[Message: abc]

2016-06-03 19:50:40,342 TRACE [http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1] impl.converter.DefaultTypeConverter  Converting java.lang.String -> java.lang.String with value: abc

2016-06-03 19:50:40,342 TRACE [http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1] camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor  Processing exchange for exchangeId: ID-DT-DBOZANOVIC-63763-1464976228255-0-1 -> Exchange[Message: abc]

2016-06-03 19:50:40,343 TRACE [http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1] impl.converter.DefaultTypeConverter  Converting java.lang.String -> java.lang.String with value: abc

2016-06-03 19:50:40,343 TRACE [http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1] camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor  Processing exchange for exchangeId: ID-DT-DBOZANOVIC-63763-1464976228255-0-1 -> Exchange[Message: abc]

2016-06-03 19:50:40,343 TRACE [http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1] camel.processor.DefaultErrorHandler  isRunAllowed() -> true (Run allowed if we are not stopped/stopping)

2016-06-03 19:50:40,344 TRACE [http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1] impl.converter.DefaultTypeConverter  Converting java.lang.String -> java.lang.String with value: abc

2016-06-03 19:50:40,344 DEBUG [http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1] camel.processor.SendProcessor  >>>> Endpoint[seda://send] Exchange[Message: abc]

2016-06-03 19:50:40,346 TRACE [http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1] impl.converter.DefaultTypeConverter  Converting java.lang.String -> java.lang.String with value: abc

2016-06-03 19:50:40,346 TRACE [http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1] component.seda.SedaProducer  Adding Exchange to queue: Exchange[Message: abc]

2016-06-03 19:50:40,347 TRACE [Camel (camel) thread #0 - seda://send] impl.converter.DefaultTypeConverter  Converting java.lang.String -> java.lang.String with value: abc

2016-06-03 19:50:40,347 TRACE [http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1] impl.converter.DefaultTypeConverter  Converting java.lang.String -> java.lang.String with value: abc

2016-06-03 19:50:40,347 TRACE [Camel (camel) thread #0 - seda://send] component.seda.SedaConsumer  Polled queue 0x753d1721 with timeout 1000 ms. -> Exchange[Message: abc]

2016-06-03 19:50:40,347 TRACE [http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1] camel.util.EventHelper  Notification of event is disabled: ID-DT-DBOZANOVIC-63763-1464976228255-0-1 exchange Exchange[Message: abc] sent to: Endpoint[seda://send] took: 2 ms.

2016-06-03 19:50:40,348 TRACE [http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1] impl.converter.DefaultTypeConverter  Converting java.lang.String -> java.lang.String with value: abc

2016-06-03 19:50:40,348 TRACE [http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1] camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor  to: Recording duration: 3 millis for exchange: Exchange[Message: abc]

2016-06-03 19:50:40,348 TRACE [Camel (camel) thread #0 - seda://send] impl.converter.DefaultTypeConverter  Converting java.lang.String -> java.lang.String with value: abc

2016-06-03 19:50:40,348 TRACE [http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1] camel.processor.DefaultErrorHandler  Is exchangeId: ID-DT-DBOZANOVIC-63763-1464976228255-0-1 interrupted? false

2016-06-03 19:50:40,348 TRACE [http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1] camel.processor.DefaultErrorHandler  Is exchangeId: ID-DT-DBOZANOVIC-63763-1464976228255-0-1 done? true

2016-06-03 19:50:40,348 TRACE [Camel (camel) thread #0 - seda://send] camel.impl.DefaultUnitOfWork  UnitOfWork created for ExchangeId: ID-DT-DBOZANOVIC-63763-1464976228255-0-3 with Exchange[Message: abc]

2016-06-03 19:50:40,348 TRACE [http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1] impl.converter.DefaultTypeConverter  Converting java.lang.String -> java.lang.String with value: abc

2016-06-03 19:50:40,349 TRACE [http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1] camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor  route: Recording duration: 6 millis for exchange: Exchange[Message: abc]

2016-06-03 19:50:40,348 TRACE [Camel (camel) thread #0 - seda://send] impl.converter.DefaultTypeConverter  Converting java.lang.String -> java.lang.String with value: abc

2016-06-03 19:50:40,349 TRACE [http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1] impl.converter.DefaultTypeConverter  Converting java.lang.String -> java.lang.String with value: abc

2016-06-03 19:50:40,349 TRACE [http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1] camel.impl.DefaultUnitOfWork  UnitOfWork done for ExchangeId: ID-DT-DBOZANOVIC-63763-1464976228255-0-1 with Exchange[Message: abc]

2016-06-03 19:50:40,349 TRACE [Camel (camel) thread #0 - seda://send] camel.util.EventHelper  Notification of event is disabled: ID-DT-DBOZANOVIC-63763-1464976228255-0-3 exchange created: Exchange[Message: abc]

2016-06-03 19:50:40,350 TRACE [http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1] impl.converter.DefaultTypeConverter  Converting java.lang.String -> java.lang.String with value: abc

2016-06-03 19:50:40,350 TRACE [Camel (camel) thread #0 - seda://send] impl.converter.DefaultTypeConverter  Converting java.lang.String -> java.lang.String with value: abc

2016-06-03 19:50:40,350 TRACE [http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1] camel.util.EventHelper  Notification of event is disabled: ID-DT-DBOZANOVIC-63763-1464976228255-0-1 exchange completed: Exchange[Message: abc]

2016-06-03 19:50:40,350 TRACE [Camel (camel) thread #0 - seda://send] camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor  Processing exchange for exchangeId: ID-DT-DBOZANOVIC-63763-1464976228255-0-3 -> Exchange[Message: abc]

2016-06-03 19:50:40,350 TRACE [http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1] impl.converter.DefaultTypeConverter  Converting java.lang.String -> java.lang.String with value: abc

2016-06-03 19:50:40,350 TRACE [http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1] camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor  Exchange processed and is continued routed synchronously for exchangeId: ID-DT-DBOZANOVIC-63763-1464976228255-0-1 -> Exchange[Message: abc]

2016-06-03 19:50:40,350 TRACE [Camel (camel) thread #0 - seda://send] impl.converter.DefaultTypeConverter  Converting java.lang.String -> java.lang.String with value: abc

2016-06-03 19:50:40,351 TRACE [http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1] impl.converter.DefaultTypeConverter  Converting java.lang.String -> java.lang.String with value: abc

2016-06-03 19:50:40,351 TRACE [http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1] camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor  Exchange processed and is continued routed synchronously for exchangeId: ID-DT-DBOZANOVIC-63763-1464976228255-0-1 -> Exchange[Message: abc]

2016-06-03 19:50:40,351 TRACE [Camel (camel) thread #0 - seda://send] camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor  Processing exchange for exchangeId: ID-DT-DBOZANOVIC-63763-1464976228255-0-3 -> Exchange[Message: abc]

2016-06-03 19:50:40,351 TRACE [http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1] impl.converter.DefaultTypeConverter  Converting java.lang.String -> java.lang.String with value: abc

2016-06-03 19:50:40,351 TRACE [http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1] camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor  Exchange processed and is continued routed synchronously for exchangeId: ID-DT-DBOZANOVIC-63763-1464976228255-0-1 -> Exchange[Message: abc]

2016-06-03 19:50:40,351 TRACE [Camel (camel) thread #0 - seda://send] camel.processor.DefaultErrorHandler  isRunAllowed() -> true (Run allowed if we are not stopped/stopping)

2016-06-03 19:50:40,351 TRACE [http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1] impl.converter.DefaultTypeConverter  Converting java.lang.String -> java.lang.String with value: abc

2016-06-03 19:50:40,352 TRACE [http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1] camel.util.EventHelper  Notification of event is disabled: ID-DT-DBOZANOVIC-63763-1464976228255-0-1 exchange Exchange[Message: abc] sent to: Endpoint[direct://send] took: 13 ms.

2016-06-03 19:50:40,352 TRACE [Camel (camel) thread #0 - seda://send] impl.converter.DefaultTypeConverter  Converting java.lang.String -> java.lang.String with value: My message: 

2016-06-03 19:50:40,352 TRACE [Camel (camel) thread #0 - seda://send] impl.converter.DefaultTypeConverter  Converting java.lang.String -> java.lang.String with value: abc

2016-06-03 19:50:40,352 TRACE [Camel (camel) thread #0 - seda://send] impl.converter.DefaultTypeConverter  Converting java.lang.String -> java.lang.String with value: My message: abc

2016-06-03 19:50:40,352 INFO  [Camel (camel) thread #0 - seda://send] sedaRoute  My message: abc

2016-06-03 19:50:40,352 TRACE [Camel (camel) thread #0 - seda://send] impl.converter.DefaultTypeConverter  Converting java.lang.String -> java.lang.String with value: abc

2016-06-03 19:50:40,353 TRACE [Camel (camel) thread #0 - seda://send] camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor  log: Recording duration: 1 millis for exchange: Exchange[Message: abc]

2016-06-03 19:50:40,353 TRACE [Camel (camel) thread #0 - seda://send] camel.processor.DefaultErrorHandler  Is exchangeId: ID-DT-DBOZANOVIC-63763-1464976228255-0-3 interrupted? false

2016-06-03 19:50:40,353 TRACE [Camel (camel) thread #0 - seda://send] camel.processor.DefaultErrorHandler  Is exchangeId: ID-DT-DBOZANOVIC-63763-1464976228255-0-3 done? true

2016-06-03 19:50:40,353 TRACE [Camel (camel) thread #0 - seda://send] impl.converter.DefaultTypeConverter  Converting java.lang.String -> java.lang.String with value: abc

2016-06-03 19:50:40,353 TRACE [Camel (camel) thread #0 - seda://send] camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor  route: Recording duration: 3 millis for exchange: Exchange[Message: abc]

2016-06-03 19:50:40,354 TRACE [Camel (camel) thread #0 - seda://send] impl.converter.DefaultTypeConverter  Converting java.lang.String -> java.lang.String with value: abc

2016-06-03 19:50:40,354 TRACE [Camel (camel) thread #0 - seda://send] camel.impl.DefaultUnitOfWork  UnitOfWork done for ExchangeId: ID-DT-DBOZANOVIC-63763-1464976228255-0-3 with Exchange[Message: abc]

2016-06-03 19:50:40,354 TRACE [Camel (camel) thread #0 - seda://send] impl.converter.DefaultTypeConverter  Converting java.lang.String -> java.lang.String with value: abc

2016-06-03 19:50:40,354 TRACE [Camel (camel) thread #0 - seda://send] camel.util.EventHelper  Notification of event is disabled: ID-DT-DBOZANOVIC-63763-1464976228255-0-3 exchange completed: Exchange[Message: abc]

2016-06-03 19:50:40,355 TRACE [Camel (camel) thread #0 - seda://send] impl.converter.DefaultTypeConverter  Converting java.lang.String -> java.lang.String with value: abc

2016-06-03 19:50:40,355 TRACE [Camel (camel) thread #0 - seda://send] camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor  Exchange processed and is continued routed synchronously for exchangeId: ID-DT-DBOZANOVIC-63763-1464976228255-0-3 -> Exchange[Message: abc]

2016-06-03 19:50:40,355 TRACE [Camel (camel) thread #0 - seda://send] impl.converter.DefaultTypeConverter  Converting java.lang.String -> java.lang.String with value: abc

2016-06-03 19:50:40,355 TRACE [Camel (camel) thread #0 - seda://send] camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor  Exchange processed and is continued routed synchronously for exchangeId: ID-DT-DBOZANOVIC-63763-1464976228255-0-3 -> Exchange[Message: abc]
```

How to make SEDA component work with a custom blocking queue instance?

Camel version: `2.13.2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to configure the queue on both SEDA endpoints.

Comment: Indeed, changing `<to uri="seda:send" />` to `<to uri="seda:send?queue=#arrayQueue" />` makes it work. Thanks!